# Can I get an EASA class 2 medical certificate, if my myopia is corrected by glasses?

Tags: medical, easa

Yes, I know somebody asked this question before but I am still confused

> (2) For a class 2 medical certificate:
>
> (i) Distant visual acuity, with or without correction, shall be 6/12
> (0,5) or better in each eye separately and visual acuity with both
> eyes shall be 6/9 (0,7) or better.
>
> (ii) Notwithstanding point (b)(2)(i), applicants with substandard
> vision in one eye or monocularity may be assessed as fit, in
> consultation with the medical assessor of the licensing authority and
> subject to a satisfactory ophthalmological evaluation.

Its says "*with or without correction*"; if the regulation is like that, it is possible for everybody to get a class 2 certificate. Because there is no limit for myopia.

I have myopia -6 (L) -5,50 (R), does this mean that I can get a class 2 certificate with glasses?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing [visual acuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_acuity) of the eyes in general with the [optical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_power) of the lenses required to correct your myopia.

Depending on where you are from, you may be more familiar with the visual acuity, or visus, expressed in 20/x (United States) or a percentage/decimal value (e.g. 80 %, 0.80) (e.g. Germany). The decimal value for acuity is also stated in parentheses in the regulation (6/12 == 0.5, 6/9 == 0.7).

Since visual acuity depends on several factors, the myopia may or may not be bad enough for you to not get a Class 2 medical. If you only achieve sufficient acuity with glasses, then the medical will require you to wear suitable glasses or contact lenses when acting as a pilot.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it's a good idea to have a consult visit with your AME with any concerns you have with your medical history BEFORE your medical exam. Your AME will be able to let you know what the cutoffs are for any conditions you're worried about.